# 301 redirect OpenCart

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

everybody

How does it possible to make 301 redirect from url like

```
/index.php?_car_=product&filtr[make]=6
```

To

```
/catalog/make/audi
```

I try to use the following code, but it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php\?_car_=product&filtr[make]=6 [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /catalog/make/audi? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that **[** and **]** are regex special chars, You need to escape special chars by using a backslash to  match them literally,try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php\?_car_=product&filtr\[make\]=6 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /catalog/make/audi? [R=301,L]
```